# How to pivot a dataframe with duplicate entries in index column?

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, pivot

I have a dataframe that I am really struggling to pivot into the correct structure, and I wanted to ask here for some assistance, because I just cannot figure out the correct index, columns, and values arguments to use. I am using python.

I have this dataframe (sorry it's long, but I felt it necessary to include everything to show the structure):

```
  Size      Color    Parameter      Estimate
---------------------------------------------
 Small       Blue           P1            XX
 Small       Blue           P2            XX 
 Small       Blue           P3            XX
 Small        Red           P1            XX
 Small        Red           P2            XX
 Small        Red           P3            XX
 Small      Green           P1            XX  
 Small      Green           P2            XX
 Small      Green           P3            XX
Medium       Blue           P1            XX
Medium       Blue           P2            XX 
Medium       Blue           P3            XX
Medium        Red           P1            XX
Medium        Red           P2            XX
Medium        Red           P3            XX
Medium      Green           P1            XX  
Medium      Green           P2            XX
Medium      Green           P3            XX
   Big       Blue           P1            XX
   Big       Blue           P2            XX 
   Big       Blue           P3            XX
   Big        Red           P1            XX
   Big        Red           P2            XX
   Big        Red           P3            XX
   Big      Green           P1            XX  
   Big      Green           P2            XX
   Big      Green           P3            XX
```

I want to somehow turn this dataframe into this:

```
               P1                     P2                      P3
         Blue    Green    Red    Blue   Green     Red    Blue   Green     Red
   Big     34      17      12      19      39      28      49      39      48
Medium     40      15      24      15      29      21      41      12      26
 Small     10      31      19      46      39      43      16      13      41
```

I have tried using `pd.pivot()` and `pd.pivot_table()`, running many combinations of:

```
df.pivot(index ='Size', columns ='Color', values =['Parameter', 'Estimate'])
```

but each time I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

How can I properly fill out the pivot table arguments so I can re-structure my initial dataframe into the target dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You need `['Parameter', 'Color']` in the `columns` argument:

```
(df.pivot(index='Size', columns=['Parameter', 'Color'], values='Estimate')
   .sort_index(axis=1))

Parameter   P1             P2             P3          
Color     Blue Green Red Blue Green Red Blue Green Red
Size                                                  
Big         XX    XX  XX   XX    XX  XX   XX    XX  XX
Medium      XX    XX  XX   XX    XX  XX   XX    XX  XX
Small       XX    XX  XX   XX    XX  XX   XX    XX  XX
```

It's possible your actual data has duplicate indices (not shown in the sample data) which means you will need to disambiguate it with `groupby` and a `cumcount`ed column and then your `index` argument will become a list of `['Size', 'cumcounted_column']`.

Comment: I tried your code and received the following error: `KeyError: 'Level Parameter not found'. Would this mean I need to use `groupby` and `cumcount` as you suggested? In the Traceback there is also this: `ValueError: 'Parameter' is not in list`, which does not make sense to me, because I clearly see it as a column in my initial dataframe.

Comment: @LostinSpatialAnalysis It's probably an index and not a column, what about trying `df = df.reset_index()` beforehand?